# Is it any possibility to take input from notepad at run time in java

Tags: java

Is it any possibility to take input from notepad at run time in java. More specifically what I write on the notepad it will consider as an input for java function at run time.

Comment: Yes, there's a possibility to do that.

Comment: How is it possible any example or direction

Comment: Are you asking how to read a file?

Comment: Do it via the clipboard?

Comment: I want to write a code in java which is waiting for user input and that particular input will provide through notepad at run time. any direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

- Use Swing/JavaFX to write a notepad app, and read the info from there.
- [Use Watchers to detect when a notepad file was updated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).